# Practical cross-spectrum estimation using Blackman-Tukey approach

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, spectrum-estimation

I would like to estimate the cross-spectrum of two signals using the (lag-windowed) Blackman-Tukey approach but I'm having difficulties with proper practical implementation. As defined in equation 2.8.32 of the the book *Spectral Analysis of Signals* (2005, Prentice Hall) by Stoica&Moses, the Blackman-Tukey periodogram estimate of the cross-spectrum between two stationary signals $ y(t)$ and $ u(t)$ (for the purpose of my question we may also assume that both signals are real-valued) is given by

\begin{align*}
\hat{\phi}_{yu}(\omega) = \sum_{k = -M}^{M}  w(k) \ \hat{r}_{yu}(k) e^{-i\omega k}
\end{align*}

where $ w$ denotes some appropriate lag-window (symmetric with $ 2M'+1$ non-zero observations, $ M' < M$ ) and $ \hat{r}_{yu}$ estimated cross-covariance function with M lags (also in total $ 2M+1$ observations). I try to implement the estimation via Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) using a typical Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithm available in most statistical packages, say MATLAB's `fft` function ([documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)).

What I am not sure about is how to perform the DFT on windowed cross-covariance values since index $k$ is taking both negative and positive values. When using MATLAB's `fft` function we feed in a vector representing the signal (with some length $N$) we want to transform and the algorithm performs the transform with index $k$ running from $1$ to $N$. As I understand it, if we were dealing with a DFT of an autocovariance function, say $ \hat{r}_{yy}$, then the negative indices would be no problem as $\hat{r}_{yy} $ is symmetric so the "two sides" around $ k = 0$ are essentially the same and one could just perform an "one-sided" DFT by feeding values $ w(m) \ \hat{r}_{yy}(m) \ , \ m = 0,1,...,M$ to the `fft` algorithm. As symmetry need not be the case with cross-covariances, my understanding is that this approach does not work. My initial solution was just to cram the windowed cross-covariance values

$$  w(k) \ \hat{r}(k) \ , \ k = -M,...,-1,0,1,...M $$

into a vector of length $ 2M + 1$ and feed it to the `fft` function as it is. However, I fear there are problems with this approach due to exponents of the DFT taking up only negative values. My question is therefore **how should one perform the DFT with a vector of (windowed) cross-covariance values in order to obtain the desired estimate of the cross-spectrum**?

Just to be clear I explicitly want to use the Blackman-Tukey / cross-covariance approach and not e.g. Welch's approach in estimation. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\hat{\phi}_{yu}(\omega) = \sum_{k = -M}^{M}  w(k) \ \hat{r}_{yu}(k) e^{-i\omega k}\tag{1}$$
apply a change of variable $$k'=k+M+1\Rightarrow k=k'-M-1$$

and $(1)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}\hat{\phi}_{yu}(\omega) &= \sum_{k' = 1}^{N}  w(k'-M-1) \ \hat{r}_{yu}(k'-M-1) e^{-i\omega (k'-M-1)}\\[10pt]
&=e^{i\omega (M+1)}\sum_{k' = 1}^{N}  w(k'-M-1) \ \hat{r}_{yu}(k'-M-1) e^{-i\omega k'}\\
&=e^{i\omega (M+1)}\sum_{k' = 1}^{N}  w'(k') \ \hat{r}'_{yu}(k') e^{-i\omega k'}
\end{align}$$

where $N=2M+1$ and $w'$ and $\hat{r}'_{yu}(k')$ are the shifted vectors as you did in your own try.

---

The above answer is when you want to use linear shift. If you wan to use circular shift, then do it like the following:

```
 x=w.*rhat;
 phi=fft(circshift(x',M+1)');
```

where `M` is even and `w` and `rhat` are just the symmetric vectors around `M+1` (for instance `w=[2 4 6 4 2]` is symmetric around `M=3`).

Comment: Thank's alot for your answer! Just to be clear, with "shifted vectors" do you mean a circular shift of the original vector so that the first M values are taken  out and shifted to the end, so that the shifted vector starts with the value corresponding to M+1th value in the original vector? Or maybe something else? Now, practically speaking, if I were to calculate the part inside the sum notation with fft should I scale the result with a complex exponent $e^{i \omega (M+1)}$?

Comment: You're welcome @vvv. We need $w'(k)=w(k-M-1)$ and $\hat{r}'_{yu}(k)=\hat{r}_{yu}(k-M-1)$. It means, both $w(k)$ and $\hat{r}_{yu}(k)$ should be shifted from $[-M, M]$ to $[1, 2M+1]$ such that the start of both are from $1$ rather than $-M$. When you did that, the inside of sum is consistent with the definition of FFT and you can calculate it. At the end, scale it with $e^{i\omega(M+1)}$

Comment: Thanks again. I'm almost there; I circularly shifted both vectors and ran the FFT. What I am wondering though is the scaling term. Consider, for example, that we are dealing with an autocorrelation function, i.e. $\hat{r}_{yy}$. My understanding is that in this case the periodogram values should be real-valued. This indeed is the case after running the FFT (up to very small imaginary terms due to numerical imprecisions, I suppose). However, if I scale these results with $e^{i \omega (M+1)}$ the results are obviously complex valued figures. Any idea what's up with this?

Comment: @vvv The answer I provided will require you to use linear shift, not circular shift. If you wan to use circular shift, then do it like the following:     
     `x=w.*rhat;`
     `phi=fft(circshift(x',M+1)');` 
where `M` is even and `w` and `rhat` are just the symmetric vectors around `M+1` (for instance `w=[2 4 6 4 2]` is symmetric around `M=3`).

Comment: Okay got it now, many thanks for your great help! Just a thought, it might be helpful to add your previous comment to your original answer as well, at least for me it did the trick (was confused about how to shift vectors).

Comment: @vvv I am glad it helped. Just updated the answer as you suggested.